# Неожиданный вывод ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть такой код.

Контроллер

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    Response.Write(RouteData.Values["id"]);
    return View();
}
```

Маршрут

```
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional
```

Вьюха обычная (внутри тегов body пусто)

Возникло два вопроса

1. Почему при запросе такого вида `http://localhost:11456/home/index/id=9` выводится результат `id=9` а не просто `9`. Ведь на входе в метод `Index` стоит тип инт, а вывод получается вроде как типа стринг ?
2. Почему запрос типа `localhost:11456/home/index?id=9` ничего не выводит ? Ведь по идее `RouteData.Values["id"] = 9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень даже ожидаемый вывод. В ASP.NET нет какой-то "магии", которая способна автоматически превратить некорректно заданные пользователем URL в правильные.

Вы задали маршрут `{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Указанные же вами пути:

```
home/index/id=9
home/index?id=9
```

Данному маршруту не соответствуют. Параметр id задан как необязательный, и в первом случае он действительно равняется  строке "id=9", а во втором случае параметра id на месте нет вообще. Что указываете, то и получаете.

Заданный вами маршрут ожидает путь вида:

```
home/index/5
```

Где `home` - название класса контролера(`HomeController`), `index` - название публичного метода(действия) контролера, а `5` - собственно значение передаваемого этому методу аргумента `id`